# Multiply number by two, per loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, variables

First of all, I know this is really basic, I just can't find an answer anywhere. So I have loop in Javascript, it'll do some stuff every time it loops. I created a global var called `age`, now I want to multiple the variable `age`, every time the loop is executed. Any ideas? Here's what I got going

```
var age = 10

for (var i = age.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(age*2);
};
```

This just seems to multiple only once, any ideas?

Comment: You're never updating the `age` variable. Use `*= 2`.

Comment: as i know - number has not property `length`

Comment: what expected output?

Comment: Trying to get `10,20,30,40,50`. That type of output, not `10,20,40,80,100`

Comment: so just `console.log(age*(age-i))`

Comment: Your desired result is not `multiplication` it is `addition`

Comment: @Idris your question and your example are inconsistent

Comment: It's been a long night, and I'm just trying to finish this up, apologizes for any mistakes. I'm trying to start with something like `10`, then loop it and get results such as `10,20,30,40,50`. But the initial `10` could be dynamic, so I can't simply add `10` @MIRMIX

Comment: @Idris What if age was 13

Comment: I'm not making any sense, my logic is way off. Let me start over. Let's start   with 100, and breaking it up into parts dynamically. So I could have 100/4, then I'd need to add 25 to each age, so I'd get 25,50,75,100. Make sense?  I'm wicked sorry for this confusion @MIRMIX

Comment: Check my solution is it what you want and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes . First one  is age.length is NaN . Second one you must keep track of changes.

You can do something like this.

```js
var age = 100
 var n=4;
 var out=0;

 for (var i = 1; i <=n; i++) { // This loop gonna be executed n times
     out += age/n;
     snippet.log(out);
 };
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: why use `out` if you can use `age`? :-)

Comment: For not losing original value :D

Comment: Slightly closer. Things are starting to make more sense. So what I tried to do was change the age to `100`, then change `n` to `3`. I then changed the `*` to `/` and I got `33.33`. Which is good, now I just need to get `66.66`. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: And like if I did `age=100`, then `n=4`, I'd want to get `25,50,75,100`

Comment: I change it accordingly @Idris

Comment: Just spent 3 hours working to solve this, I can't thank you enough. You've made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the value of age

```js
var age = 10

for (var i = age; i > 0; i--) {
  age *= 2;
  snippet.log(age);
};
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```js
var age = 10

for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
  age = age * 2;
  alert(age);
};
```

`age.length` has no sense since age is not an array.
I used `i=10` but you can define something else there or use another variable.
In your code you console.log each time age * 2.
You have to store the current value of age backto age in order to get the  new *2 value of it.

Answer (score 0):

To get results like `10,20,30,40,50` I would use **addition** instead of **multiplication**

if you don't know what `age` is, then you need to make a copy of it;

```
var age = 10;
var operand = age;
while (age <= 100){
    console.log(age);
    age = age + operand;
}
```

Comment: Numbers would be dynamic, so I couldn't simply add 10. I'm currently taking 100, and breaking it up into parts dynamically. So I could have `100/4`, then I'd need to add `25` to each age, so I'd get `25,50,75,100`. Make sense?

Comment: @Idris this is a completely different question to the one asked

Answer (score 0):

as i understand from your comment you should change your code like

```js
var age = 10,
    part = 100/age

function print(val){
  document.getElementById('r').innerHTML += val + '<br/>';
}

for (var i = part - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(age*(part-i));
    print(age*(part-i))
};
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```

also i think simples would be change loop condition like

```js
var age = 10,
    part = 100/age;

function print(val){
  document.getElementById('r').innerHTML += val + '<br/>';
}

for (var i = 1; i < part; i++) {
    console.log(age*i);
    print(age*i)
};
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```